# GMAT Question: If $\frac{a-b}c > 0$, is $c < 0$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, fractions

Two pieces of information that we get:

(1) $ a^{2} < b^{2} $

(2) $ \frac{b}{c} < \frac{a}{c}$

My question now refers to the statement (2). In the solution, it is told that (2) is not sufficient since $ \frac{b}{c} < \frac{a}{c}$ can be simplified to $\frac{a-b}{c} > 0$, which is the same information we already got in the question itself. However, why could we not simplify the 2nd statement like this:

$ \frac{b}{c} < \frac{a}{c}$ -->
multiplying both sides with c leads to $b<a$? And if $a$ is always larger than $b$, then $c$ MUST be positive, or am I wrong? Then statement (2) would be sufficient for me, since the answer would always be no.

What am I missing? I appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Something is wrong with the question: When $a=-1,b=-2,c=\color{red}{+}1$ then (1) and (2) hold.

Comment: Note that you are assuming $c$ is positive when you "multiplying both sides with c leads to b < a". Otherwise, the inequality will have to change signs. We can multiply by $c^2$, but not by $c$.

Comment: Ah, thanks Calvin, that makes sense. I missed that one.

Comment: The next time you ask a question, please put the entire question in the "body" of the question (the big box under the words "Include all the information someone would need to answer your question"). You can put part of the question in the title (this is often very helpful), but then you should repeat it in the body. For a question from a test, it is best to present the question in the "body" exactly as it was presented on the test, that is, all parts of the question as originally written and in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

If $c >0$, then (2) gives $a >b$. Note this holds regardless of the signs of $a$ and $b$. So you have for example $a = 1 > b = -5$, which also satisfies  (1) $a^2 < b^2$.
So you found an example where (1) and (2) hold for $c >0$.

This means that $c <0$ is *not* implied by the conditions.

The trick of this question is to try and trap you into thinking of positive values only.